How to remove border in TextField reactjs

I want to remove the border of TextField
<Box display="flex" alignItems="center" border="1px solid #ccc" borderRadius="4px" paddingLeft="10px">
    <Typography variant="body1" sx={{ marginRight: 2, color: 'grey' }}>
        URL
    </Typography>
    <Divider orientation="vertical" flexItem sx={{ marginX: 2 }} />
    <TextField variant="outlined" defaultValue="testing" InputProps={{ readOnly: true, }} fullWidth />
</Box>


You can remove the border using sx props as:
  <TextField
    variant="outlined"
    defaultValue="testing"
    InputProps={{
      readOnly: true,
      sx: {
        "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
          border: "none",
        },
      },
    }}
    fullWidth
  />

Check out this codesandbox demo I created!
